# Scikit SGD classifier with independent class results?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have done multi-class classification with scikit.
But I want independent prediction of each class results, instead of summing them into 1.

I know, its as similar to Multi-label. But have to generate independent 0-1 value for each classes in the predicted output.

```
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(alpha=0.001, loss="log", random_state=42,
                                            max_iter=100, shuffle=True, verbose=1))


Output:
[0.04188954 0.01330129 0.01330501 0.02050405 0.03726504 0.01412006
 0.01753864 0.01250115 0.02342872 0.0124999  0.05234852 0.0161394
 0.01250032 0.01330749 0.01403075 0.0149792  0.0125048  0.01250406
 0.01412335 0.01413113 0.01412246 0.06543099 0.01249486 0.01250054
 0.01308784 0.01330463 0.01250242 0.02252353 0.02037271 0.0133038
 0.01250215 0.0125009  0.01537566 0.02023355 0.01600915 0.01762224
 0.01496796 0.01496522 0.01412407 0.01250198 0.01239722 0.01249967
 0.01763284 0.01573462 0.01250276 0.01451515 0.01330437 0.01329294
 0.01249999 0.01485671 0.01249419 0.01858113 0.01250192 0.01585085
 0.01330439 0.01250573 0.01250585 0.01715666 0.01249392]
```

Summing this I got 1. But I want each of them to compare with 0-1 independently. How could its possible?

As per scikit notes, **"In the single label multiclass case, the rows of the returned matrix sum to 1."**

Ref: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html

How to override this?

Created 2d matrix:

```
The shape of matrix is (342, 2)

[[  4   0]
 [  4   0]
 [  4   0]
 [ 21   0]
 [ 21   0]]
```

Got error as:

> **ValueError: Multioutput target data is not supported with label binarization**

Using label binarizer I got (349,59) There are 59 labels and 349 samples.

**Using MultiOutputClassifier**

```
clf = SGDClassifier(loss="log", random_state=42, verbose=0)
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(clf)
```

**Result:**

```
clf.predict_proba(x_test)

[array([[0.99310559, 0.00689441]]), array([[0.9942846, 0.0057154]]), array([[0.0051056, 0.9948944]])]
```

As per comment, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.predict_proba

Result is having 3 classes.

How do I interpret it into single value?
Ex: array([[0.99310559, 0.00689441]]) => 0.5 or o.6

Comment: Are you fitting a vector of label or a matrix ? : **This strategy can also be used for multilabel learning, where a classifier is used to predict multiple labels for instance, by fitting on a 2-d matrix in which cell [i, j] is 1 if sample i has label j and 0 otherwise** .

Comment: @BornTbeWasted I used LabelBinarizer and converted the labels. 
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
How do I convert this to [i, j] ?

Comment: Create a 2-d matrix : for each sample, give them the sum of the converted labels :
e.g [ 0 0 ... 1 ... 1 ...0], and then add that row to a "label" that you will give to the classifier

Comment: @BornTbeWasted I have updated the question. created 2D array. But could not train it.

Comment: Sorry , I wasn't clear, when I said sum , it was considering the vectorial operator , not sum(list). Your matrix is supposed to be of shape(number_of_samples,number_of_labels). You have 59 labels right ?

Comment: Yes. 59 labels.

Comment: Well then create a vector of size 59 , for each sample , representing the labels he has .

Comment: @BornTbeWasted Using label binarizer i got (342, 59)

Comment: Perfect now feed that to your classifier instead of the previous vector

Comment: I tested with two samples. and Two classes. The prediction is still sum upto 1.
0.6609374995561297 
0.3390625004438703 
@BornTbeWasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve the problem as multi-label problem, then use `multiOutput` wrapper instead of `OneVsRestClassifier()`.

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import preprocessing

X,y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

clf = MultiOutputClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='log',max_iter =10))
lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
y_onehot = lb.fit_transform(y)
clf.fit(X, y_onehot)

clf.predict_proba([X[0]])
```

output:

```
[array([[0., 1.]]),
 array([[1.00000000e+00, 5.63826474e-52]]),
 array([[1., 0.]])]
```

Second element is the probability of given record belonging to that class. Now, you can see the probability of all the classes does not sum to 1.

Comment: I'm applying changes..!

Comment: I have updated the question. Check it. The results are strange. I have 3 classes. @ai_learning

Comment: Why is it strange? The model is saying that `x_test` is more likely to be 3rd class.

Comment: see here [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.predict_proba] to understand probability array. It is prob. output of 3 binary classification models

Comment: Yes. That's the third class. 
This is having positive result of two classes.

[array([[0.99365778, 0.00634222]]), array([[0.00615999, 0.99384001]]), array([[0.99309583, 0.00690417]])]

I couldn't figure out. @ai_learning

Comment: Even all there classes could have positive values, since its a independent model.

Comment: I have updated the question. You are right. BUt all of them are saying nearly 99%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191653/discussion-between-ai-learning-and-giri-annamalai-m).